# Detecting killed nodes with Akka Cluster

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, splitbrain

I'm working on a project using Akka Cluster 2.4.8.

Is there a way to detect crashed nodes (as in `computer failure`, `kill -9`, etc) with AkkCluster ?

I'm currently have a 3-node environment, using the `static-quorum` split brain resolve strategy.

```
akka.cluster.split-brain-resolver {
    active-strategy = static-quorum
    stable-after = 5s

    static-quorum {
        quorum-size = 2
        role = ""
    }
```

I was hoping that when killing an instance, the remaining cluster members would mark it as `DOWN`. However, it remains `UNREACHABLE` (see below). Is there a way to achieve this?

```
clusterStatus": {
    "members": [
        {
            "uniqueAddress": {
                "address": {
                    "protocol": "akka.tcp",
                    "system": "test-actor-system",
                    "host": "test-out-00",
                    "port": 2552
                },
                "uid": 1998600863
            },
            "upNumber": 1,
            "status": "Up",
            "roles": []
        },
        {
            "uniqueAddress": {
                "address": {
                    "protocol": "akka.tcp",
                    "system": "test-actor-system",
                    "host": "test-out-01",
                    "port": 2552
                },
                "uid": 1371217592
            },
            "upNumber": 3,
            "status": "Up",
            "roles": []
        },
        {
            "uniqueAddress": {
                "address": {
                    "protocol": "akka.tcp",
                    "system": "test-actor-system",
                    "host": "test-out-02",
                    "port": 2552
                },
                "uid": -796176254
            },
            "upNumber": 2,
            "status": "Up",
            "roles": []
        }
    ],
    "unreachable": [
        {
            "uniqueAddress": {
                "address": {
                    "protocol": "akka.tcp",
                    "system": "test-actor-system",
                    "host": "test-out-01",
                    "port": 2552
                },
                "uid": 1371217592
            },
            "upNumber": 3,
            "status": "Up",
            "roles": []
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Do you have a Lightbend Reactive Platform subscription (sorry, could be a silly question but it's worth asking)?

Comment: @svezfaz Not a silly question, but I do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split-brain resolver is a commercial feature of Akka for which you need a Lightbend subscription.

> Note
>
> This is a feature of the Typesafe Reactive Platform that is exclusively available for Typesafe Project Success Subscription customers.
>
> To use the Split Brain Resolver feature you must install Typesafe Reactive Platform.

Chances are, if you're not a Reactive Platform subscriber, your split-brain configs are just plainly ignored.

Full docs at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/rp-15v09p02/scala/split-brain-resolver.html

Comment: Oh, thats good yo know. Guess I'll have to do It myself. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not using Akka 2.4+. I've started my project with akka 2.3.12 and I still use it. At that time there was no split-brain plugin solution provided by akka, the only advice was to set:

```
# put to off in order to not have split brain
auto-down-unreachable-after = off
```

This meant, in order to avoid split brain, you had to manual remove UNREACHABLE nodes, and back in 2.3.12 the akka-microkernel (that was later deprecated http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Microkernel_is_Deprecated) gave you the possibility to issue a command to the cluster to mark the node with issues as DOWN

```
bin/akka-cluster localhost 9999 down akka.tcp://MySystem@darkstar:2552
```

So a bit of user-needed action to manage the split-brain and to take a node out of the cluster, it may be the same case with your (Akka Cluster 2.4.8) version.